# MathLink Excel version 3.5 & 3.6 inconsistency

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, excel

I bought and installed Mathematica Link for Excel 3.6.0. However, after installation, it appears inside Excel as Version 3.5.0.

Has anyone seen this issue?

I have emailed Wolfram support but have not received an acknowledgement after a week.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It is most likely just a string value that someone forgot to update.